# DateTime equivalent of Sql Server 2008 in PostgreSQL 9.2

Tags: postgresql, sql-server-2008-r2, postgresql-9.2

Should i be using timestamp or timestamp with time zone in PostgreSql 9.2? Which one matches the datetime version of Sql Server 2008.

Comment: Why don't you experiment a little and see for yourself?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Datetime in MS SQL server has no timezone so that would match timestamp in postgresql. I don't expect it matters but postgresql has "only" microsecond precision while MS SQL has 100 nanosecond precision.